# Read file as template, execute it and write it back

Tags: file, templates, go, io

I'm trying to parse CSS files in which variables can be injected that are defined in a config file. Currently the function does:

1. Opens the file based on the given path argument
2. Parses the file's content
3. Executes the template by injecting the config variable
4. Writes the rendered content to the console instead of the original file

```
func parse(path string) {
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }

    // Parse requires a string
    t, err := template.New("css").Parse(string(f))

    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }

    // A sample config
    config := map[string]string {
        "textColor": "#abcdef",
        "linkColorHover": "#ffaacc",
    }   

    // Execute needs some sort of io.Writer
    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, config)  

    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Can't execute ", path)
    }
}
```

My problem is that `template.Parse()` requires the content as string and `template.Execute()` an `io.Writer` as argument. I tried to open the file with `os.Open()` which returns a file object that implements the `io.Writer` interface. But how can I get the file's content as a string from such a file object in order to use it with `Parse()`?

Comment: I try to extend a static side generator. Therefore I need to do this only once.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [ParseFiles](http://godoc.org/text/template#ParseFiles) to parse the template. This code basically does the same thing as calling ReadFile, template.New and Parse as in the question, but it's shorter.

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles(path)
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return
}
```

Use [os.Create](http://godoc.org/os#Create) to open the output file.

```
f, err := os.Create(path)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("create file: ", err)
    return
}
```

A file is an io.Writer. You can execute the template directly to the open file:

```
err = t.Execute(f, config)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("execute: ", err)
    return
}
```

Close the file when done.

```
f.Close()
```

[Complete working example on the playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/Kuo18jwuSm)

Comment: I use `os.Walk("root", filterFunc)` and a filter to find all css files. if the script found one it calls `parse()` with the path. So, does it makes sense to call `ParseFiles()` if I need only to parse a single file? And lastly: `os.Create(path)` will overwrite the original file, right?

Comment: For this scenario, you should call ParseFiles with a single file at a time.  Caling ParseFiles with a single file saves code as noted in the answer. Yes, this overwrites the original file. If that's not what you are asking in the question, then please clarify.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, thanks @CeriseLimón I needed this too. Could you please explain what this is? Never seen this before `map[string]string`

Comment: @Sbe88 It's a [map](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) with string keys and string values.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function I made with Cerise Limón's answer

```golang
func createFileUsingTemplate(t *template.Template, filename string, data interface{}) error {
    f, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    err = t.Execute(f, data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```